# PHP: Adding multiple products to post order form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm building a sort of php shop that will allow a user to enter amounts for various products and then a form will process the order. There is no payment processing etc. What I am struggling to do is add each product to each amount to send through to the order form as a $_POST variable.  Currently my ordered items are a standard form:

```
<input type="text" id="value" name="ordered-items[]" />
```

I thought I could add the product ID as a hidden variable, but that will just add it for every product.

```
<input type="hidden" id="value" name="products[<?php the_id(); ?>]" />
```

How can I marry up the product to the order quantity and then send that to the order form for processing, this part I can do myself.

Thanks In advance

Comment: id's cannot be duplicated in a page. Name the product field and quantity field with some portion of the product's name or SKU.

Comment: The id's are appearing as this is inside a Wp_Query loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the product quantity based on it's ID like this:

```
<input type="text" name="item[<?php the_id(); ?>]" />
```

You can then access the product quantities on the server side using for each:

```
foreach($_POST as $index => $value){
// $index is product id and $value is product quantity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the quantity in a separate input field. In case of a normal text field the visitor can then even change the quantity:

```
<input type="text" id="item1" name="ordered-items[]" /><input type="text" id="qty1" name="quantity[]" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="item2" name="ordered-items[]" /><input type="text" id="qty2" name="quantity[]" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="item3" name="ordered-items[]" /><input type="text" id="qty3" name="quantity[]" />
```

In php you can process the data like this:

```
<?php

$items = $_POST['ordered-items'];
$quantities = $_POST['quantity'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
  echo $items[$i] . ' has quantity ' . $quantities[$i];
}
```

Comment: Would I then check if they had any value at the products end before submission, otherwise the form would post every product??